"Route does not exist" in JSON:API for custom entity type
I created a custom entity type using drush generate entity:content.  I chose to have bundles, and I added a bundle test_bundle.
I can add my custom entities at admin/content as expected.
However, when I access the entity type via JSON:API, I'm get an error:
 "errors": [
    {
      "title": "Internal Server Error",
      "status": "500",
      "detail": "Route \u0022jsonapi.log_json--test_type.collection\u0022 does not exist.",
      "links": {
        "via": {
          "href": "https://example.ddev.site/jsonapi"
        },
        "info": {
          "href": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1"
        }
      }
    }

I tried deleting the entity bundle and creating a new entity bundle and I get the same error with the name of the new bundle.
I also tried deleting all bundles, in which case I get this error:
      "detail": "Route \u0022jsonapi.log_json_type--log_json_type.collection\u0022 does not exist.",
How do I fix this? I've created other custom entities with drush and I haven't had this problem accessing them via JSON:API before.

The error was a RouteSubscriber that was restricting the route as described here.  Make sure nothing is calling alterRoutes() and modifying the JSON:API response.
